# How to iterate over a mongoose schema inside another schema and update data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have two mongoose.Schema Collection: `Cities` and `Countries`, the *Cities* contain only cities like this:

```
{city_name: "Berlin"},
{city_name: "Heraklion"},
```

*Countries* has also a `city_name` path like this:

```
{city_name: "Heraklion"},
{city_name: "Berlin"},
```

My intention is to use my `updateCountries()` function and at every iteration to check if the `city_name` value is present in Country.city_name too and if true to save the ObjectIds inside `cities_ObjectIds` array.

It's work so far but the still unresolved problem is that its add only one `ObjectId` (the last founded). If you have any idea please help.

***updateCountries()***

```
const updateCountries = async () => {
    let cities = await Cities.find({});
      cities.map((e) => {
        Countries.updateMany(
          { city_name: e.city_name },
          { cities_object_ids: e._id }
        ).then(() => {});
      });
```

***Countries Schema***

```
const CountriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
       city_name: String,
        cities_ObjectIds: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Cities',
          },
        ],
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.

The problem was that the [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator was missing. `$push` is an array-update-operator that append items to array if the conditions are met.

```
const updateCountries = async () => {
  let cities = await Cities.find({});
  cities.map((e) => {
    Countries.updateMany(
 { city_name: e.city_name, cities_object_ids: { $ne: e._id } }, // $ne check if e._id is not already in the array
      { city_name: e.city_name },
      { $push: { cities_object_ids: e._id } }
    );
  });
};
```

I'm not really sure if this is a good practices approach at all or maybe I should look rather for **aggregation stage** with `$lookup` to performs a **left outer join** to collection.

Any suggestions are welcome!